# UICollectionView didSelectAt c разными ячейками

Tags: ios, swift

Есть `UICollectionView` в котором я использую две разных `UICollectionViewCell`

В зависимости от условий заполняю одной или второй ячейкой.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if (indexPath.row == 3 || count == 1)
    {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NoPetsViewCell.key, for: indexPath) as? NoPetsViewCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
        return cell
    } else {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: RatingViewCell.Key, for: indexPath) as? RatingViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

И проблема начинается когда пытаешься выделить ячейку.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NoPetsViewCell.key, for: indexPath) as? NoPetsViewCell {
        presenter.presentAddPet()
    } else {
        presenter.presentDetailView(for: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

И при выделении любого типа ячейки он все равно считает что ячейка принадлежит к `NoPetsViewCell` и выполняет `presenter.presentAddPet()`.
при использовании `is` вместо `as` ситуация не меняется.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто проверить ячейку на соответствие нужному типу. Попробуйте так:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? NoPetsViewCell != nil {
        presenter.presentAddPet()
    } else {
        presenter.presentDetailView(for: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```